# Add new form code for customer_form_attribute in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, database, install-script

I added new customer fields (attributes) by installer in my Magento extension. I want group this fields and show in separate tabs on customer edit page.

I can make it in installer with this code

```
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', $attr_code)
    ->setData('used_in_forms', [$form_code])
    ->save();
```

But for this I need add new value to enum list for field **form_code** in table **customer_form_attribute**

I know how make this with SQL in mysql console:

1. Check enum list by *SHOW CREATE TABLE customer_form_attribute*
2. Change column by *ALTER TABLE customer_form_attribute ...*

But I need make this modification in my extension installer.

How I can make it?

Comment: Can you add your full install script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. It working on my local server. Don't try on production yet.

There is code for modify column **form_code** in table **customer_form_attribute**

```
$form           = 'my_new_form_code';

$table_array = $installer->getConnection()->describeTable('customer_form_attribute');
if (isset($table_array['form_code'])) {
    if (stripos($table_array['form_code']['DATA_TYPE'], $form) === false) {
        $table_array['form_code']['DATA_TYPE'] = substr($table_array['form_code']['DATA_TYPE'], 0, -1) . ", '" . $form . "')";
        $installer->getConnection()->modifyColumn('customer_form_attribute', 'form_code', $table_array['form_code']['DATA_TYPE'] . " NOT NULL");
    }
}
```